# how to create a another parent node inside parent node

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database

I have post method in nodejs I am using firebase as database.

what i wanted to achieve was to created another parent node inside my parent node using the date.

```
router.post('/updateStatus/:uuid', function (req, res) {
    var ref = database.ref('watchers/' + req.params.uuid);
    var body = req.body; 

    strtdate = body['datebook']; // body['datebook'] has a value of 2018-04-09.
    console.log(body['datebook']);
    body['availability'] = {strtdate:{bookingId:body['bookingId'],isBooked:'true',serviceLocation:body['location'],shift:body['shift']}};

    ref.update(body);

    res.send('success');

});
```

[image]

this is the current output. instead of datebook it is supposed to be a date.

Comment: Please post output of `console.log(body['datebook'])`

Comment: i wrote it above its 2018-04-09

Comment: No from console chrome Is it creating an object. Also snapshot of node before updating.

Comment: the result from console was 2018-04-09 as is.. i put the strtdate on res.send(strtdate)

Comment: i cant figure it out on why the value doesn't show's up...

Comment: Try to add a new value to check if it is showing or not if it is then there is problem with update method and if not then problem is with creating the object

Comment: the output of the req.body was {bookingId'-13id41',datelook:'2018-04-09',shift:'night'}

Comment: what should be the output for the strtdate?. it should be an object? string? array?

Comment: Add square brackets for `strdate` to inject its value as key. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [ECMA6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) Object key syntax

> the object initializer syntax also supports computed property names.
>   That allows you to put an expression in brackets [], that will be
>   computed and used as the property name.

```
let strtdate = body['datebook'];
let obj = Object.assign({}, {[strtdate]:{bookingId:'-13id41',shift:'night'}})
ref.update(obj);
```